# Grease pencil darker and thicker before lifting stylus

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm kind of a newbie to the grease pencil tool, and while trying the different brushes I've noticed after a while that any line I draw is a bit darker, thicker and more opaque but then go back to their normal material look when I lift the stylus from the line. It's really annoying and I can't seem to find what could be the parameter for this, but I've noticed it won't do this on a new file. I've already tried to copy and paste my drawing in a new file, but the grease pencils material are linked to the strokes and it won't change anything.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've found the answer: It only happens on layers with a sub 1 opacity. I hope this helps anyone with the same issue.